# Send 1 notification after column updated by *multiple* UPDATE statement in same transaction

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I need to send a notification in the format of `column updated from {old value} to {new value}`

I tried to use trigger, but it will run after **each update statement**. So if I update the column from `A` to `B` ,then to `C`

```
update test_table set test_column = 'B' where id = 0 -- column updated from A to B
update test_table set test_column = 'C' where id = 0 -- column updated from B to C
```

Even if they under same transaction, **two** notifications will be sent.

Any way I can send only **one** notification `column updated from A to C`?

* the example above is just for demonstration, the actual update queries are quite complex and cannot be combined into one

Sample trigger

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[testing_trigger]
    on [dbo].[test_table]
    for Update
AS 
BEGIN
    if  Update(test_column)
        BEGIN

            insert into test_notification
            select ttd.test_column as old_value , tti.test_column as new_value
            from inserted tti
            inner join deleted ttd on tti.id = ttd.id
            where ttd.test_column  <> tti.test_column

        END
END
```

Comment: What do you expect when 2 rows are updated? What about when 1,000 are? What about if 10 columns and 10,000 rows are updated?

Comment: If 10,000 rows updated,  it should send 10,000 notifications (actually each records belongs to a specific user so the notification will be send to the corresponding user). And I only need to monitor 1 specific column

Comment: If you need to do that, you're going to need to introducing looping into your trigger; a truly **terrible** idea. Why? Because `PRINT` is limited to 8,000 bytes of characters, so you would never be able to report 10,000 row changes in a single `PRINT` (so you'd need to loop to ensure you don't exceed 8,000 bytes in a single `PRINT` statement). You would be far better off using an `OUTPUT` clause to `INSERT` the `inserted` and `deleted` values into a (temporary) table, and then you can `SELECT` the rows from table where the value of `{Column}` differs.

Comment: I am already using `inserted` and `deleted` to diff , while using `insert into select` to create notification. The problem is duplicated notification because trigger ran twice

Comment: Post the *actual* trigger you have then, as the above doesn't `PRINT` anything. But, again, I suggest *not* doing this in a trigger.

Comment: Included a sample trigger, my notification is just a table , no sure what `PRINT` does

Comment: The problem here is that `if  Update(test_column)` doesn't do what you *think* it does. Again, you need to check the values of the columns and if it differs in `inserted` and `deleted`.

Comment: Please check my sample trigger, I already comparing `test_column` in `inserted` and `deleted`. If you suggest not using trigger. Please help to propose a way to fulfill the requirement without using trigger.

Comment: In the scenario you gave, you *did* do 2 updates, so of course you get 2 notifications. A became B, and then B became C. We don;t, however, have details of what process if doing to notifying; clearly that is something else. Perhaps you need to get the "first" value for the original and "last" value for the updated values for details that haven't been notified about in your process there. You would determine those using `ROW_NUMBER` again the date and time column you are using to log the date and time of the change.

Comment: You mean I essentially need to record each updated value using trigger, and just before commit I can do my notification logic?

Comment: No, I mean in your notification logic.

Comment: The normal way to handle such notifications is to insert them into an event table, then have a process/service which reads the events out and processes them. That way the trigger runs super quick and does the minimum amount of work possible. If you were using an event table you could detect 2 (X) similar events such as you mention and group them to create a single notification.

Comment: And how do you know which row has been updated, as you are not passing through the primary key into the notification table?